# Faking Return value with F# and FakeItEasy

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fakeiteasy

I am trying to use FakeItEasy to mock an interface defined in C#

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int HeartbeatInterval { get; set; }
}
```

In the F# test i do

```
let myFake = A.Fake<IMyInterface>()

A.CallTo(fun () -> ((!myFake).HeartbeatInterval)).Returns(10) |> ignore
```

Running this in the test runner results in

`` System.ArgumentException
Expression of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,System.Int32]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Int32' ``

In fact it would seem that it does this for any return type e.g. if HeartbeatInterval returned type of `foo` then the exception thrown would be for type `foo` instead of `System.Int32`.

Am i doing this wrong or is there some incompatibility between F# and FakeItEasy?

It has crossed my mind that using an Object Expression might be an easier way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would venture a hypothesis that the "Easy" in "FakeItEasy" stands for "[Easy Over Simple](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy)". The library *says* it's "easy", and that is probably true if you're using it from C#. Because it is quite obviously designed for use with that language. But it is far from "simple", because it is using C#-specific syntactic tricks that are hidden from view and don't work in F# well.

The specific gotcha you're getting right now is a combination of two things: (1) F# functions are not the same as C# `Func<T,R>`, and (2) F# overload resolution rules are different from C#.

There are three overloads of [`CallTo`](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/blob/develop/src/FakeItEasy/A.cs#L108) - two of them take an `Expression<_>`, and the third one is a "catch-all", taking an `object`. In C#, if you call this method with a lambda-expression as argument, the compiler will try its best to convert the lambda-expression to an `Expression<_>` and call one of the specialized methods. F#, however, does not make this effort: F#'s support for C#-style `Expression<_>` is very limited, primarily focused on compatability with LINQ, and only kicks in when there are no alternatives. So in this case, F# chooses to call the `CallTo(object)` overload.

Next, what would the argument be? F# is a very strict and consistent language. Apart from some special interop cases, most F# expressions have a definite type, regardless of the context in which they appear. Specifically, an expression of the form `fun() -> x` will have type `unit -> 'a`, where '`a` is the type of `x`. In other words, it's an F# function.

At runtime, F# functions are represented by the type `FSharpFunc<T,R>`, so that is what the compiler will pass to the `CallTo(object)` method, which will look at it and, unable to understand what the hell it is, throw an exception.

To fix it, you could make yourself a special version of `CallTo` (let's call it `FsCallTo`) that would force the F# compiler to convert your `fun() -> x` expression into an `Expression<_>`, then use that method instead of `CallTo`:

```
// WARNING: unverified code. Should work, but I haven't checked.
type A with
    // This is how you declare extension methods in F#
    static member FsCallTo( e: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<_,_>> ) = A.CallTo( e )

let myFake = A.Fake<IMyInterface>()

// Calling FsCallTo will force F# to generate an `Expression<_>`, 
// because that's what the method expects:
A.FsCallTo(fun () -> ((!myFake).HeartbeatInterval)).Returns(10) |> ignore
```

**However,** as you have absolutely correctly observed, this is way too much of a hassle for mocking up an interface, since F# already has a perfectly statically verifiable, runtime-cost-free, syntactically nice alternative in the form of object expressions:

```
let myFake = { new IMyInterface with 
                 member this.HeartbeatInterval = 10
                 member this.HeartbeatInterval with set _ = ()
             }
```

I would totally recommend going with them instead.

Comment: There is if course the alternative of actually using that overload that takes object instead, completely avoiding the expressions. A.CallTo(someObject).WhenArguments...

Comment: @Patrik what would `someObject` be in that case?